# Binary Tree counting nodes in prolog

Tags: prolog

I built the binary tree that has the stucture bt(Data,LeftTree,RightTree).

```
btree(nil).
btree(bt(_,L,R)) :- btree(L), btree(R).
```

then I want to define predicate count1Child(Tree, Count) that assert that Count is the number of nodes in the tree that have one child. I know how to count the total number of the nodes in the tree. But no idea with counting node with only one child.

Comment: please give an example what you mean by "counting node with only one child"

Comment: for example, bt(1,bt(2,nil,bt(3,nil,nil)),bt(nil))). 1 and 2 are the nodes with only one child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cbt(nil, 0).
cbt(bt(_,L,R), T) :- cbt(L,Nl),cbt(R,Nr),
    ( (L=nil,R\=nil ; L\=nil,R=nil) -> C = 1 ; C = 0 ),
    T is Nl + Nr + C.
```

but the test tree you give in your question seems not valid: I tested with

```
?- cbt(bt(1,bt(2,nil,bt(3,nil,nil)),nil),N).
N = 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you start to write a predicate, let's try to define a predicate that gives `true` for the nodes you want to count and `false` for those nodes that still may occur but that do not count. By that we implicitly also define what we want.  I assume that you want only nodes that have two subtrees.

```
singlechild_t(nil, false).
singlechild_t(bt(_,nil,bt(_,_,_)), true).
singlechild_t(bt(_,bt(_,_,_),nil), true).
singlechild_t(bt(_,nil,nil), false).
singlechild_t(bt(_,bt(_,_,_),bt(_,_,_)), false).


tree_count(P_2, T, N) :-
   tree_count(P_2, T, 0,N).

tree_count(_, nil, N,N).
tree_count(P_2, T, N0,N) :-
   T = bt(_,L,R),
   if_(call(P_2, T), A = 1, A = 0),
   N1 is N0+A,
   tree_count(P_2, L, N1,N2),
   tree_count(P_2, R, N2,N).

 tree_countsingles(T, N) :-
    tree_count(singlechild_t, T, N).
```

(using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868))

Comment: I got the idea, but (if_/3) causes error on every tree except for nil. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @bbbBB: You need to follow the link above  and include the definition of `if_/3`.